# Create account with social login (facebook) and authenticate it angular-fullstack generator

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-oauth, angular-fullstack, social-authentication

I'm facing a problema with social signup because its not logging after its created as in local signup. When redirects, api/users/me is not accessible..is unauthorized (401), different from what i get in local signup, that redirects with user information.

in **facebook/index.js** I have default gets

```
  .get('/', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['email', 'user_about_me'],
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    session: false
  }))

  .get('/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    session: false
  }), auth.setTokenCookie);
```

and in **auth.service.js** I have the default functions

```
function isAuthenticated() {
  return compose()
    // Validate jwt
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
      // allow access_token to be passed through query parameter as well
      if (req.query && req.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
        req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token;
      }
      validateJwt(req, res, next);
    })
    // Attach user to request
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
      User.findByIdAsync(req.user._id)
        .then(function(user) {
          //user here is undefined, it shouldn't be. i want to find out why.
          if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).end();
          }
          req.user = user;
          next();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          return next(err);
        });
    });
}

function signToken(id, role) {
  return jwt.sign({ _id: id, role: role }, config.secrets.session, {
    expiresInMinutes: 60 * 5
  });
}

/**
 * Set token cookie directly for oAuth strategies
 */
function setTokenCookie(req, res) {
  if (!req.user) {
    return res.status(404).send('Something went wrong, please try again.');
  }
  var token = signToken(req.user._id, req.user.role);
  res.cookie('token', token);
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

Could anyone help me with this...Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have very similar problem. any help ?

Comment: @Chandru [here](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/1450#issuecomment-162242064) you'll find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. I had modified Angular full-stack code with a customizable backend URL.

https://github.com/kannach/AFSPhonegap/blob/master/client/components/services/config.service.js

I was testing the facebook login in localhost, whereas my backend url was pointing to my production server. Once I chanded the backed url to localhost, then everything worked as expected

Comment: you can take a look in the link I've posted above...that is the problem I was facing it. (sorry about delay to answer...)